# How to set propTypes to HOC child?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-proptypes

Given the following code:

```
const PricingCard = withLanguage(({ t, onConfirm }) => {
  const { colors } = useTheme();

  return (
    <RNPricingCard
      color={colors.primary}
      title="Premium"
      price="$7"
      info={t("premium.card.advantages")}
      button={{
        title: t("premium.card.becomePremiumPremium"),
        titleStyle: styles.buttonTitle,
      }}
      onButtonPress={onConfirm}
    />
  );
});
```

Trying to set propTypes to PricingCard like this:

```
PricingCard.propTypes = {
  t: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  onConfirm: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};
```

Produces an error, as the "t" method is given by "withLanguage". How can I solve this?

> Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `t` is marked as required in
> `<<anonymous>>`, but its value is `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

`PricingCard` is the result of calling the higher-order component, not the anonymous component you're wrapping (which is where you meant to apply prop types). If you want to add prop types for `t`, move the anonymous component to a named variable like so:

```
const PricingCardImpl = ({ t, onConfirm }) => {
  const { colors } = useTheme();

  return (
    <RNPricingCard
      color={colors.primary}
      title="Premium"
      price="$7"
      info={t("premium.card.advantages")}
      button={{
        title: t("premium.card.becomePremiumPremium"),
        titleStyle: styles.buttonTitle,
      }}
      onButtonPress={onConfirm}
    />
  );
}
PricingCardImpl.propTypes = {
  t: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  onConfirm: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

const PricingCard = withLanguage(PricingCardImpl);
```

Even better would be to use a hook-based api for accessing `t`. Or, you could skip the prop type for `t` since you know for sure you're providing it via the `withLanguage` HOC.